# Nativescript searchBar property keyboardType not working

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have this element:

```html
 <SearchBar
      hint="Search..."
      textFieldHintColor="whitesmoke"
      keyboardType="TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER"

    >
</SearchBar>
```

But still showing normal keyboard. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyboardType` is not a valid attribute on SearchBar. But you may able to achieve it by calling [setInputType(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView#setInputType(int)) on the native view.

**HTML**

```
<SearchBar
      hint="Search..."
      textFieldHintColor="whitesmoke"
     (loaded)="onLoaded($event)"

    >
</SearchBar>
```

**TS**

```
onLoaded(event) {
  if (event.object.android) {
    event.object.android.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works, but got error in `android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`. `text` it's not defined.

Comment: You must be conflicting `android` namespace with a local variable, make sure you use exact code and if you still have issues please share a Playground sample.